# Why I getting an error while trying to use map on data that i get using hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I trying map data which i get using custom hook that recives data from my "storage" (which is actually a class with array of objects and async function to get them) i reciving an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').
Code of hook:

```
const useCreations = () => {
  const service = new aboutPisanka();
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(123 )
    service.getAllCreations().then((data) => setData(data));
  }, []);

  return data
};
```

Code of element:

```
  const data = useCreations();
  console.log(data);
  const cards = data.map((data) => {
    const { heading, text, id, image } = data;
    return (
      <div key={id}>
        <img src={require(image)}/>
        <h1>{heading}</h1>
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Code of function in class where data stores:

```
  getAllCreations = async () => {
    return this._creations;
  };
```

(Sorry for my bad english)

As I understand it happens because it maps data before it gets to state but I don't have any idea how to fix it only making high order componen which will wrap my element.

Comment: Initialize data with an empty array: const [data, setData] = useState([]);

Comment: which part is where the error lies?

Comment: data.map((data)=>  please select different name for your parameter

Comment: Just initialize your data as an empty array: `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` (Notice `[]` inside the `useState`

Comment: Also `data.map((data) => {` is better written as `data.map(({ heading, text, id, image }) => {` and remove `const { heading, text, id, image } = data;` line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is initialize as `undefined`. So when the render runs before you assign an array value to data, your `.map` function fails because you call that on an `undefined`. Just initialize your data as an empty array.

```
const useCreations = () => {
  const service = new aboutPisanka();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); // NOTE: Initialization as an empty array

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(123 )
    service.getAllCreations().then((data) => setData(data));
  }, []);

  return data
};
```

Also, you could use es6 de structuring to improve readability (subjective).

```
  const data = useCreations();
  console.log(data);
  const cards = data.map(({ heading, text, id, image }) => (
      <div key={id}>
        <img src={require(image)}/>
        <h1>{heading}</h1>
        <p>{text}</p>
      </div>
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your whole code however if you are receiving data in correct format after a while because of Api response,you can add `?` in cards `const cards = data?.map((data) => {` to fix that error

Comment: yes, i receiving data in correct format, and your solution worked does this `?` checks is there any data?

Comment: Yes it's called Optional Chaning. Here is more detailed information about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining . Could you please choose it as accepted answer, if it solved your problem :)